# JavaFX- Get image of one ImageView and assign it to another ImageView

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I am doing an application which user by clicking on an image(ImageView1) can see that in another ImageView2. so I try to get the image of ImageView1 in a variable

```
BufferedImage img= SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(ImageView1.getImage(), null);
```

And then assign that variable to ImageView2

```
ImageView2.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(img, null));
```

But it seems however, setImage is done successfully, but ImageView2 is not showing anything. anyone can help me for a better solution?

Here is the code example:
Controller. ImageView1

```
@FXML
private void HandleMousePressedOnImageOne()
{
    BufferedImage img= SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(ImageOne.getImage(), null);

    try
    {       
        ImageSelection imgSelection= ImageSelection.getImageSelectionInstance();
        imgSelection.SetBufferedImageOne(img);

        FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader();
        SplitPane p= loader.load(getClass().getResource("ImageSelection.fxml").openStream());
        ImageSelectionController imgSelectionController= (ImageSelectionController)loader.getController();

        imgSelectionController.HandleImageOne();
        System.out.println("Image One has been Pressed!");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Model.ImageSelection

```
public class ImageSelection {
private BufferedImage bufferedImageOne;

private static ImageSelection imageSelectionInstace= new ImageSelection();

private ImageSelection(){}

public static ImageSelection getImageSelectionInstance()
{
    return imageSelectionInstace;
}

public void SetBufferedImageOne(BufferedImage img)
{
    this.bufferedImageOne= img;
}

public BufferedImage getBufferedImageOne()
{
    return this.bufferedImageOne;
}
```

}

Controller2.ImageView2

```
public void HandleImageOne(){
    ImageSelection imgSelection= ImageSelection.getImageSelectionInstance();
    BufferedImage img= imgSelection.getBufferedImageOne();
    ImageOne.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(img, null));
}
```

Comment: why are you going through swing? Can you stay within fx?

Comment: I am not doing any swing is FX, I got some idea from this link how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729386/cant-get-image-from-imageview-in-javafx but I donot know if this is a proper way for such case or not?

Comment: BufferedImage is an AWT struct and you use Swing conversion utils to do conversion from Fx image to this one and then back. You could use `javafx.scene.image.Image` directly instead.

Comment: What the previous comment meant was: why are you converting the JavaFX image to a buffered image and then back to a JavaFX image again. What is wrong with `ImageView2.setImage(ImageView1.getImage());`?

Comment: However, if the code you posted isn't working, then the simpler way of doing it won't work either. Something else is wrong in the code you haven't posted.

Comment: These two ImageViews are in two controllers. I am not expert in JavaFX but I do not want to use any instance of controller in another controller (Dependencies between controllers!) so I have created a class in model layer to hold (setImageView) and get (getImageView) to be able to call it from those controller.

Comment: Well clearly you have not done that in a way that works correctly. (I agree on not having dependencies between controllers, but wouldn't it be better to have an `ObjectProperty<Image>` in the model and add listeners to it from the controller(s)?) Can't really help as we can't see the code.

Comment: @James_D I updated the question with my more code structure

Comment: Your second image is contained in the `SplitPane` you called `p`: you never display that `SplitPane`, so you never display the image view. So you don't see the change in image.

Comment: you are right .. controller is SplitPane. I have only use that to get instance of controller. inside Controller2. ImageOne has been assigned to ImageView via scene builder. I expected when I use setImage to ImageOne, ImageOne updates with the image.am I missing something?

Comment: @James_D do you know any better solution for such scenario?

Comment: "Am I missing something". Only what I previously explained: the `ImageView` whose image you are setting is not displayed. So you don't see anything happen when you set the image.

Comment: And a better solution would be to use an `ObjectProperty<Image>` in the model, and observe it from the second controller. The all the first controller has to do is set the property. I'll post something when I am back at the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are loading a new copy of the UI defined in the FXML file `ImageSelection.fxml`. You don't display this new copy. When you retrieve the controller from the loader that loads that copy of the UI and call

```
imgSelectionController.HandleImageOne();
```

you change the image in the `ImageView` that is part of that new instance of the UI. Since that instance is not displayed, you don't see any effect from that call.

A better approach, which also avoids your first controller having a dependency on the second controller as in your code, is to create an `ObjectProperty<Image>` in your model, and observe it from the second controller:

```
public class ImageSelection {

    private final ObjectProperty<Image> image = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private static ImageSelection imageSelectionInstance= new ImageSelection();

    private ImageSelection(){}

    public static ImageSelection getImageSelectionInstance() {
        return imageSelectionInstance;
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty() {
        return image ;
    }

    public final void setImage(Image image) {
        imageProperty().set(image);
    }

    public final Image getImage()
    {
        return imageProperty().get();
    }

}
```

and in the second controller, do

```
public class ImageSelectionController {

    @FXML
    private ImageView imageOne ;

    public void initialize() {
        ImageSelection.getImageSelectionInstance().imageProperty()
            .addListener((obs, oldImage, newImage) -> imageOne.setImage(newImage));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now all the first controller needs to do is set the image in the model:

```
@FXML
private void handleMousePressedOnImageOne() {
    ImageSelection.getImageSelectionInstance().setImage(imageOne.getImage());
}
```

Note that there's absolutely no need to convert from a JavaFX image to a `BufferedImage` and back.

I also recommend not using a singleton pattern, for a number of (well-documented; just google "what is wrong with using singletons") reasons. Create a single instance and pass it to each of the controllers, or use a dependency injection framework to manage that for you.

Comment: very clean solution .. thanks for it. And also thanks for your point about singleton .. I learned a lot