# nested child call to super parent

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

i m new to javafx so please ignore my silly question here is problem i m facing from  2 day it would we great if any body help me
i have super parent (main view) in that country fxml view get loader 
and in country fxml i have one more fxml(call table) that loaded into country
when user click on any data of table view new fxml file get loaded and that file i want to get load into parent i had used super parent stack pane id it throw an error please help me why this happening any solution  link ,code or suggestion it will save my day
here is code

```
ObservableList<addcountryController> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private Pagination pagination;
@FXML
private AnchorPane cresult;
@FXML
private StackPane stackconsearch;
@FXML
private StackPane stackhome;
@FXML
private AnchorPane stackanc;
@FXML
private StackPane stackcountry;
@FXML
private TableView<addcountryController> tableUser;
@FXML
private TableColumn<addcountryController, String> columnName;
@FXML
private TableColumn<addcountryController, String> columnDesc;
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;

public void setText(String first,String sec){
    this.country.setText(first);
    this.desc.setText(sec);
}


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    databaseHandler = DatabaseHandler.getInstance();
    initCol();

        String qu = "SELECT * FROM country_tbl ";
        ResultSet rs = databaseHandler.execQuery(qu);
            try {
                while (rs.next()) {
                 String id= rs.getString("id");
                 String name= rs.getString("countryname");
                 String description = rs.getString("descr");
                 String country2char= rs.getString("country2char");
                 String descrshort = rs.getString("descrshort");
                 data.add(new addcountryController(id,name, description,country2char,descrshort));
                }
            }catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(addcountryController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

         tableUser.setItems(null);
         tableUser.setItems(data);

         tableUser.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
         tableUser.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<addcountryController>() {
         public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends addcountryController> c) {
             try {

                 Stage primaryStage=new Stage();
                 FXMLLoader loader =new FXMLLoader();
                 loader.load(getClass().getResource("/region/updatecountry.fxml").openStream());
                 updatecountryController usercontroller=(updatecountryController)loader.getController();
                    for (addcountryController p : c.getList()) {
                     String ADDID=p.getId();
                     String ADD=p.getName();    
                     String ADD1=p.getDescriptionshort();
                     String ADD2=p.getDescription();
                     String ADD3=p.getCountrychar();
                     usercontroller.setText(ADDID,ADD,ADD1,ADD2,ADD3);
                   }
                    StackPane root = loader.getRoot();                      
                    stackconsearch.getChildren().clear();
                    stackconsearch.getChildren().add(root);


             } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
          }
        });
}
```

here is my editcontroller

```
         private StackPane stackhome;
@FXML
private StackPane stackconsearch;
@FXML
private AnchorPane cresult;
@FXML
private TextField country;
@FXML
private TextField desc;

public void add(ActionEvent event) {
    String ADD=countrycode.getText();
    try {
        if(ADD.isEmpty()){
                Alert alert=new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setHeaderText(null);
                alert.setContentText("Please Fill All DATA");
                alert.showAndWait();
                return;
        }
        FXMLLoader loader =new FXMLLoader();
        loader.load(getClass().getResource("/region/newCountry.fxml").openStream());

        MainController usercontroller=(MainController)loader.getController();
        usercontroller.setText(ADD);
        StackPane root = loader.getRoot();
        stackconsearch.getChildren().clear();
        stackconsearch.getChildren().add(root);

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void search(ActionEvent event) {
    String countrytxt=country.getText();
    String desctxt=desc.getText();
    if(countrytxt.isEmpty() && desctxt.isEmpty())   {
        try{
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/region/cresult.fxml").openStream());

            StackPane root = fxmlLoader.getRoot();
            root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/application/application.css").toExternalForm());

            countryController usercontroller=(countryController)fxmlLoader.getController();
            usercontroller.setText(countrytxt,desctxt);
            cresult.getChildren().clear();
            cresult.getChildren().add(root);        
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        try{
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/region/cresult.fxml").openStream());
            StackPane root = fxmlLoader.getRoot();
            countryController usercontroller=(countryController)fxmlLoader.getController();
            usercontroller.setText(countrytxt,desctxt);
            cresult.getChildren().clear();
            cresult.getChildren().add(root);        
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

here is main controller

```
  @FXML
private StackPane stackhome;
@FXML
private AnchorPane Mainview;
@FXML
private AnchorPane stackanc;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root =FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@FXML
public void country(ActionEvent event) {

     FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/region/country.fxml").openStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        StackPane root = fxmlLoader.getRoot();
        stackhome.getChildren().clear();
        stackhome.getChildren().add(root);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

here is stackhome is super parent and stackcountry is parent and child of super parent     and i have one more parent stacksub which is child of stackhome,stackcountry and it has child called as stackchild i want to load this stackchild to stackhome but it not working any suggestion

Comment: Please, Edit your question sharing  a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your stack errors so we can help better.

Comment: Sorry but your code isn't expressive and doesn't represent the problem you did present, it's hard to see where the problem might be, the stacktrace and exceptions need to be added too.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288878/javafx-get-image-of-one-imageview-and-assign-it-to-another-imageview

Comment: @James_D can you give more concise example